# Programmatically append values to entity reference field of node with a dynamic field name

Tags: 8, nodes

I understand that I can append values to an entity reference field to a node normally with this method

```
$node->field_tags[] = [
    'target_id' => $my_id,
  ];
```

However I have a function like so

```
function addTag($node,$field,$id){
$node->set($field,[
    'target_id' => $id,
  ]);
}
```

In other words I have to anticipate any field the user supplies. Looking at the node class here

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/class/Node/8.2.x

I did discover the set function that lets me specify a field and a value but I don't believe that this would append to an array of entities in a field.

How would I append to an entity reference field to a node if the field name is supplied in a variable?

Comment: You could just use variable variables: `$node->{$field}[] = ...`, but I wouldn’t be surprised if the API offered something more pleasing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the class [Node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/class/Node/8.2.x) is a good starting point to look for an OOP way:

Click on [get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Aget/8.2.x), which returns a field object [FieldItemList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemListInterface.php/interface/FieldItemListInterface/8.2.x), where you can use the method [appendItem()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21ListInterface.php/function/ListInterface%3A%3AappendItem/8.2.x):

```
$node->get($field)->appendItem([
  'target_id' => $id,
]);
```

Replace `->get()` with `{}` and `->appendItem()` with `[]` and you get the shorter version which @Clive mentioned in the comment:

```
$node->{$field}[] = $id;
```

This is possible because of the  magic method [ContentEntityBase::__get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3A__get/8.2.x) and the [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface the field implements. I've also dropped `target_id`, because you don't need this for the main property of a field.

Comment: Great that worked! What's better practice? The oop way or the other?

Comment: You can't go wrong by using OOP. But I've seen both and all possible combination in between.